# Prevent to crash if assertion failed (alsa is not configured correctly)

Tags: c, alsa

if alsa mixer is not configured correctly by user crash with
alsa_get_unmute_volume: Assertion `elem' failed

```
static const char alsa_core_devnames[] = "default";
static char *card, *channel;
static int muted = 0;
static int mutecount = 0;
static snd_mixer_t *handle = NULL;
static snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = NULL;

static long alsa_min, alsa_max, alsa_vol;

static int alsa_get_unmute_volume( void )
{
    long val;
    assert(elem);

    if (snd_mixer_selem_is_playback_mono(elem)) {
        snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_MONO, &val);
        return val;
    } else {
        int c, n = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        for (c = 0; c <= SND_MIXER_SCHN_LAST; c++) {
            if (snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_channel(elem, c)) {
                snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_FRONT_LEFT, &val);
                sum += val;
                n++;
            }
        }
        if (! n) {
            return 0;
        }

        val = sum / n;
        sum = (long)((double)(alsa_vol * (alsa_max - alsa_min)) / 100. + 0.5);

        if (sum != val) {
           alsa_vol = (long)(((val * 100.) / (alsa_max - alsa_min)) + 0.5);
        }
        return alsa_vol;
    }
}
```

crash

```
alsa_get_unmute_volume: Assertion `elem' failed. Aborted (core dumped)
```

it is possible to prevent this in code?

I think that problem is here. When user set by hand, in gtkentry, wrong value of device and channel, for example /dev/mixer:line, and press enter, program crash

Code to set mixer device and channel ( correct value eg., hw:0/Line, default/CD, ...) is this:

```
static int alsa_set_device( const char *devname )
{
    int i;

    if (card) free(card);
    card = strdup( devname );
    if( !card ) return -1;

    i = strcspn( card, "/" );
    if( i == strlen( card ) ) {
        channel = "Line";
    } else {
        card[i] = 0;
        channel = card + i + 1;
    }
    alsa_open_mixer();
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf( stderr, "mixer: Can't open mixer %s, "
                 "mixer volume and mute unavailable.\n", card );
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can build with -DNDEBUG to disable asserts... but if elem is NULL here, I wouldn't expect the code you posted to do anything sensible.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to recompile ALSA to disable assertions. When you defined `NDEBUG` assertions are disabled.

Note that if an assertion failed, even if you disable the assertions probably your program will crash or get an undesired behavior.

An assertion is something that should always be true, if it is false someone made a mistake somewhere.